# Firebase child syntax performance

Tags: firebase

I'm starting a project and setting the code style guide. I like the second of the two below, but I'm wondering if there is a difference in the way these two statements are executed? Is the second one slower, or is the whole chain evaluated before any call to the database happens? (I only see a single frame in the socket)

Style 1:

```
db.child(`data/projects/${currentProject}/boxes/${newBoxId}`).set(true);
```

Style 2:

```
  db
    .child('data')
    .child('projects')
    .child(currentProject)
    .child('boxes')
    .child(newBoxId)
    .set(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference between the two.

Calling `child()` does not require the client to connect to the server, it's a pure client-side operation. So you can do whatever is most readable in your code.

If I have a set of static segments in the path, I typically combine them in a single `child()` call. But when there is a dynamic segment, I prefer to put that into its own `child()` call to prevent having to concatenate strings.

```
ref.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('documents/passport').on('value'...
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Frank.

Comment: FWIW I've written a little helper to _slightly_ shorten my lines: `getRef('data/projects', projectId, 'boxes', boxId).update(box);` (gist: https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/d7bc056170057bc9d16252f42302e4d7)

Comment: Nice. Somewhat shorter (though not necessarily as readable): `['data/projects', projectId, 'boxes', boxId].join('/')`